# Reining in the Axiom of Power Set in ZF

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Given the powerset operator $\mathit P$, we have the following mapping

$\tag 1 \mathcal \Phi: \mathbb N \to \Phi(\mathbb N) $
$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \, n \mapsto \mathit P^n(\mathbb N)$

> What happens if we take away the Axiom of Power Set in $ZF\pm C$ and replace
>   it with $\text{(1)}$? Would this contradict the other axioms?

Comment: Incidentally, there are some very interesting results on the "amount of powerset" (or really, "powerset-along-replacement") we need in various situations. Most famously, Harvey Friedman showed that [more and more iterations of powerset are needed to prove determinacy further and further up the Borel hierarchy](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484371900180).

Comment: On formatting: You can use pairs of L& R dollar-signs  to "display"  a line instead of typing \quad \quad \quad ..., and to put un-formatted text (like "because") in a displayed line, enclose it within \text {...}, like \text { because }.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I've felt silly at times trying to (perfectly)  align stuff since the final result might depend on the display device. But anyway, not exactly sure what you mean. Please share some links with useful mathstackexchange formatting technique so I can copy n paste it in the future.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Another interesting paper, 'Large irredundant sets in operator algebras' https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.01511?context=math I don't know  the formulation for the $\text{♢-Axiom}$ (stronger than the continuum hypothesis), but my guess is all modern day physics can be expressed/modeled in $V_{\omega+\omega} + \text{♢}$. I wonder how this holds up:
"...every open set of Minkowski spacetime is associated with a C*-algebra" /wikipedia.

Comment: Did something not work with the [Ask Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) page that you felt the need to ask a completely disjoint question on a page where you already accepted one answer?

Comment: Also, is there a reason that you didn't check [WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_principle), or search the internet before asking for an intuitive explanation of a technical axiom?

Comment: On formatting: I've only read the tutorials on the Help page. For myself, I don't bother much with alignment. Sometimes I do  a "dummy edit" of a Q or A just to see how to format something that I didn't  know , or forgot. E.g.. whose idea was it that $\nabla$, which in analysis is called "del", should be \nabla ?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes, but if you 'dummy edit' my stuff you will be brought to tears! And I don't consider myself anal-retentive, but really, worrying about (perfect) alignment and extra blank lines, etc.? Seriously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by (1) you mean the existence of the operator $\Phi$ that you defined above. As you say, the existence of such a $\Phi$ is a consequence of the Powerset Axiom and of the other axioms of $ZF$, so if (1) contradicts the other axioms, the Powerset Axiom does as well.

Moreover, it seems to me that $V_{\omega_1}$ is a model of $ZFC-P+(1)$, so the consistency strength of this theory is strictly less that that of $ZFC$.

Comment: Just $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is already enough.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for your comment. Since I am not extremely familiar with this topic and I wanted to be sure I opted to go for a regular cardinal, in order to be "safer". If I may add something to this, my answer would be wrong if we considered collection instead of replacement, right? What should we use as a model in that case?

Comment: Correct, for Replacement we use $H(\kappa)$, the set of sets which are hereditarily smaller than $\kappa$.